# Getting traceroute of ip using tcp in android? or any other options except for icmp?

Tags: android, tcp, icmp, ttl, traceroute

Im looking for a way to use traceroute on android that does not allow icmp which means i can not build it using ping and ttl in icmp as I already tried that